# Can't update state array using hooks on findIndex condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a bunch of data as such

```
const myArr = [
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "bench", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "squat", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "shoulder", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "deadlift", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "deadlift", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "squat", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "bench", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "bench", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "shoulder", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "b", exercises: [{ exercise: "shoulder", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "shoulder", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "bench", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "squat", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "situps", sets: 2 }] },
];
```

I am trying to store each 'exercise' that is listed, I don't need a tally of them just if it occurs once, stick it into the state array and ignore it if it comes up again so as not to add it again. i.e as an example

```
const results = ['Deadlift', 'Bench', 'Squats', 'Shoulder']
```

Outside of react, I could just use something as such and I'd store each value the one time:

```
const storage = [];

for (let item of myArr) {
    for (let i of item.exercises) {
        if (storage.findIndex((v) => v === i.exercise) === -1) {
            storage.push(i.exercise);
        }
    }
}
console.log(storage);
```

However I can't get this to work within useEffect and useState hooks. Say I have the same data, If I do the same script inside useEffect it pays no attention to whether the string is already inside the state hook array, and will just seemingly add it anyway, regardless of my findIndex condition. So I end up with each exercise repeating however many times it occurs within the data as opposed to just the single reference to it.

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (allEntries.loaded) {
            for (let item of allEntries.entries) {
                for (let i of item.exercises) {
                    if (myState.findIndex((v) => v === i.exercise) === -1) {
                        setMyState((prev) => [...prev, i.exercise]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }, [allEntries]);
```

Can someone explain where I've gone wrong?

Comment: [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) looks like a perfect candidate here if you want to have the exercise name only once in it.

Comment: Dedupe (into temporary array-variable), then update your state with resulting array.

Comment: Classic case of a [stale closure](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function), if you need an up-to-date value for `myState` inside the effect, then `myState` has to be part of the dependency array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatMap` and `Set`:

```
const myArr = [ <your data> ]
const uniqueExercises = [
  ...new Set(myArr.flatMap(x => x.exercises).map(x => x.exercise))
]
```

directly with `setState`:

```
setState([
  ...new Set(entries.flatMap(x => x.exercises).map(x => x.exercise))
])
```

```js
const myArr = [
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "bench", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "squat", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "shoulder", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "deadlift", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "deadlift", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "squat", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "bench", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "bench", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "shoulder", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "b", exercises: [{ exercise: "shoulder", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "shoulder", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "bench", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "squat", sets: 2 }] },
    { test1: "", test2: "a", exercises: [{ exercise: "situps", sets: 2 }] },
];
console.log([...new Set(myArr.flatMap(x => x.exercises).map(x => x.exercise))])
```

Comment: Is their no way to do this directly via the useState hook?

Answer (score 0):

Although this has already been answered, I thought I might as well put this here anyway.

You can create a temporary new state and modify that directly without having to worry about the async nature of setState updates.

For Example:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (allEntries.loaded) {
        setMyState(currentState => {
            const newState = [...currentState];

            for (let item of allEntries.entries) {
                for (let i of item.exercises) {
                    if (newState.findIndex((v) => v === i.exercise) === -1) {
                        newState.push(i.exercise);
                    }
                }
            }

            return newState;
        });
    }
}, [allEntries]);
```

To avoid having to use `myState` inside of the `useEffect`, which some linters will complain about if you don't add it to the dependency array, you can move more of the `useEffect` code inside of the `setMyState` callback function.